# Python HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm error

Tags: python, debugging

I am new to programming. I want write a parser for the beginning.

Code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
url = 'https://example.com'
username = 'login1'
password = 'pass'
p = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
p.add_password(None, url, username, password)
handler = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm(p)
opener = urllib.build_opener(handler)
urllib.install_opener(opener)
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = f.read()
print ("html")
```

I get error in IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\project\parser.py", line 8, in <module>
    handler = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm(p)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for `urllib.request.HTTPPassowrdMgrWithDefaultRealm`, the `__init__` method looks like this:

```
__init__(self)
```

That `self` is provided implicitly.  You're trying to pass it a second positional parameter (`p`), hence the error message.

Take a look at the Basic Authentication example in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#id5), which offers the following example usage:

```
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of None.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib.request.urlopen use our opener.
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
```